# error Access to extended visibility flags denied: Requires com.sonymobile.permission.SYSTEM_UI_VISIBILITY_EXTENSIONS permission

Tags: android, xamarin, android-camera, sony-camera-api

I am working on mob app based on sony camera , but while running I am getting this error message -

> error Access to extended visibility flags denied: Requires
>   com.sonymobile.permission.SYSTEM_UI_VISIBILITY_EXTENSIONS permission.

can you tell me how to resolve this error and why we add this permission in app.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an specific issue of Sony devices.

Add this permission to your AndroidManifest file, as the same level as your application tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sony.mobile.permission.SYSTEM_UI_VISIBILITY_EXTENSION" />

<application...>

        .......

</application>
```